# CSS changing border length

Tags: html, css, border

Is there a way to change the border length. i know i can use border-left, border-right etc, but  lets say i want only 70% of the circle to have a border.  Is there any way to do so or maybe use some plugin?

http://jsfiddle.net/ncx4ct9u/2/

```
.circle{
 height:90px;
 width:90px;
 border-radius: 50%;
 -moz-border-radius: 50%
 -webkit-border-radius:50%;
 background:green;
border:3px solid black;
}
```

Comment: there is a css way but it's not simple, look here for a way to solve the issue
http://codepen.io/AtomicNoggin/pen/fEish

Answer (score 0):

There is the border-top-left: property, however I do not think this will let you only a 70% radius.

Have you considered using an image of a circle instead of creating one with html?